# Codeigniter - Unable to call system's lang() function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to call lang() function that is part of codeigniter's system/helpers (language_helper.php), resulting in a Fatal error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function lang()

$def_actions['add'] = array('name' => lang('carbogrid_add'), 'alias' => 'add', 'url' => $this->add, 'icon' => 'ui-icon-circle-plus', 'toolbar' => TRUE, 'grid' => FALSE);
```

Comment: Have you loaded the language_helper before call?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to load the helper before doing that:

```
$this->load->helper('language');

$def_actions['add'] = array('name' => lang('carbogrid_add'), 'alias' => 'add', 'url' => $this->add, 'icon' => 'ui-icon-circle-plus', 'toolbar' => TRUE, 'grid' => FALSE);
```

Comment: Shoot! I thought I autoloaded that, but just checked and didn't. Thanks, this worked - `$this->CI->load->helper('language');`