# Codeigniter- Fatal error: Call to undefined function lang()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know what error is it. I run on local and it is working fine, but when I try to run on the live server it gave me this error.

### Fatal error:

> Call to undefined function lang() in /var/www/html/my_system/application/controllers/usermanagement/usermanagement_main.php on line 672

```
$this->load->model('user/user','user');
$this->load->model('tablecode/code_academic_qualifications');
$this->load->model('tablecode/code_certifications');

//Initialize content
//$content['pagetitle'] = lang('eqb_title_userregistration');
$content['userid'] = $userid;
$content['pagefunction'] = lang('eqb_title_edituserprofile'); //<-- line 672
$content['nav'] = lang('eqb_title_userregistration');
$content['updating_user'] = TRUE;
$content['display_form_as'] = 'editing';

$tabletypearray = array('code_city','code_country','code_disability','code_gender','code_marital_status','code_postcode','code_race','code_religion','code_state');
$content['basicfields'] = $this->user->get_all_basic_form_data($tabletypearray);

$content['current_acl_user'] = $this->ezrbac->getCurrentUser();

$content['user_profile_information'] = $this->user->get_complete_user_profile_information_byid($userid);

$acad_data = $this->user->get_user_academic_profile($userid);
```

Comment: The function `lang()` is undefined, its right there in the error message. Probably not being included / you're missing files on your live server.

Comment: You can refer to this link for the similar case as your. [Fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032997/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-lang-in-ci-merchant-using-cardsave)

Comment: `lang` is not a function, if you're using language you must you `$this->lang->line('eqb_title_edituserprofile')`

Comment: Here is the doc on it https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html#loading-a-language-file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716050/codeigniter-unable-to-call-systems-lang-function Refer to this question. I think it might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for all of ur idea. I will check it back later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the helper before doing that:

```
$this->load->model('user/user','user');
$this->load->model('tablecode/code_academic_qualifications');
$this->load->model('tablecode/code_certifications');

$this->load->helper('language'); // You have to load the helper before doing that:

//Initialize content
//$content['pagetitle'] = lang('eqb_title_userregistration');
$content['userid'] = $userid;
$content['pagefunction'] = lang('eqb_title_edituserprofile'); //<-- line 672
$content['nav'] = lang('eqb_title_userregistration');
$content['updating_user'] = TRUE;
$content['display_form_as'] = 'editing';

$tabletypearray = array('code_city','code_country','code_disability','code_gender','code_marital_status','code_postcode','code_race','code_religion','code_state');
$content['basicfields'] = $this->user->get_all_basic_form_data($tabletypearray);

$content['current_acl_user'] = $this->ezrbac->getCurrentUser();

$content['user_profile_information'] = $this->user->get_complete_user_profile_information_byid($userid);

$acad_data = $this->user->get_user_academic_profile($userid);
```

Comment: Thanks sir. I'll try it back.

Comment: I try the solution and it worked. But I have another problem, the label didnt show up infront of my textfield. Did you know why?

Comment: please share the view part of your code. @MuhammadRezuan

Comment: <span class="pagefunction">
    <span class="pagenavitab">
        <a class="navfunction" href="<?php echo site_url('usermanagement/usermanagement_main/users_listing'); ?>">Senarai Pengguna Berdaftar</a>
    </span>
</span>

<fieldset>
  <legend><?php echo 'Sunting Profil Pengguna (Bahagian I)';//strtoupper($pagefunction); ?></legend>

Comment: <?php        
  $attrib = array('id' => 'userupdateform','name'=>'userupdateform');
  echo form_open_multipart('usermanagement/usermanagement_main/process_update_form',$attrib); 
?>

<fieldset style="background-color: #D5EAF0;">
<legend>Maklumat Wajib</legend>
<ol class="undecorated_ol">  
  <li>
    <label for="firstname"><?php echo lang('eqb_name'); ?><span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span></label>
    <?php if($display_form_as == 'viewing') { ?>

Comment: <?php echo (!empty($user_profile_information['firstname']))?"<span style='color:#000000;'>".$user_profile_information['firstname']."</span>":''; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>